# Getting an error when trying to fetch keys from NEAR network via near-cli

Tags: nearprotocol

When running the command: `near keys XXXXXXX.near` I'm getting the error below, I'm expecting that near-cli is using the mainnet network by default, but there seems to be an issue, as it says there is no account, but the account clearly exists.

```
An error occured
TypedError: [-32000] Server error: account XXXXXX.near does not exist while viewing
    at JsonRpcProvider.sendJsonRpc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:158:27)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async JsonRpcProvider.query (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:66:24)
    at async Account.fetchState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:47:23)
    at async Account.state (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:54:9)
    at async Near.account (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/near.js:41:9)
    at async exports.keys (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/index.js:195:19)
    at async Object.handler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:39:9) {
  [stack]: 'Error: [-32000] Server error: account XXXXX.near does not exist while viewing\n' +
    '    at JsonRpcProvider.sendJsonRpc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:158:27)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)\n' +
    '    at async JsonRpcProvider.query (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:66:24)\n' +
    '    at async Account.fetchState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:47:23)\n' +
    '    at async Account.state (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:54:9)\n' +
    '    at async Near.account (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/near.js:41:9)\n' +
    '    at async exports.keys (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/index.js:195:19)\n' +
    '    at async Object.handler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:39:9)',
  [message]: '[-32000] Server error: account XXXXXXX.near does not exist while viewing',
  type: 'UntypedError',
  context: undefined
}
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps the username is misspelled https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/issues/1106

Comment: This error was happening for me when I'd accidentally overwritten my file at `~/.near-credentials/testnet/subacctexample.myaccount.testnet.json`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the `NODE_ENV=mainnet` variable with the near-cli to specify which networkId to connect to. This worked for me `NODE_ENV=mainnet near keys account.near`